# C# params method using member expressions with mixed property types

Tags: c#, types, properties, expression, parameters

I've written a params method which accepts member expressions and observed, that the compiler won't accept mixed property types from the expressions. Here is my code

```cs
public class MyClass<TEntity>
{
  public MyMethod<TEntity> Column<TProp>(params Expression<Func<TEntity, TProp>>[] expressions)
  { ... }
}

public class Customer
{
  property int Id {get; set;}
  property string Name {get; set;}
  property int Age {get; set;}
}

var mc = new MyClass<Customer>();
mc.MyMethod(c=>c.Id, c=>c.Age); // Works fine, using 2 int types
mc.MyMethod(c=>c.Id, c=>c.Name); // Results into a compile error, using int and string type mixed
```

I know, that the compiler creates from keyword params an array, but that array is of type `Expression<Func<TEntity,TProp>>`
 Can this be solved, without replacing the params keyword with lots of overloads of MyMethods and increasing parameter list ?

Comment: What exactly does `MyMethod` do? Could you replace `TProp` with `object`?

Comment: Your method signature and your example code are not compatible. It would be easier to help you, if you had a compilable example.

Comment: The answer is: no. You can't make it work with `params` when you expect generic type to be different in the items you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your parameter type to `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>`.
2. Add the following code to get the actual members:

   ```
   public void MyMethod(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] expressions)
   {
       var members = from expression in expressions
                       let cast = expression.Body as UnaryExpression
                       let member = (expression.Body as MemberExpression)
                                   ?? cast.Operand as MemberExpression
                       where member != null
                       select member.Member;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, replaced TProp with object and added your code to access the MemberExpression and now it works like I wanted it ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you don't seem to have a single `TProp`, you can as well replace it with `object` and make it non-generic:

```
public MyMethod<TEntity> Column(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] expressions)
```

Comment: Yes, it will make it compile. But I doubt it will be very useful as you'd have to use reflection to see what's actual type of delegate that was wrapped in `Expression`.

Comment: Argh, replacing TProp with object make it compile, but than, the expression is no longer og type MemberExpression, which I need...